# How to get value from spring controller class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller class in spring. I am passing values such as a simple string or a hashmap. I know how to get values in thymeleaf. I want to get values on my html page in pure javascript, no thymeleaf. My controller class :

```
    String s="RUSSIA";
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String Country( Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("country", s);
    return "index";
    }
```

Now I want to get this string in javascript variable. I am using HTML not JSP.

Comment: There are a large number of ways you can do that. Without knowing what libraries you're using on the JS side and what browsers you're targeting, we can't possibly suggest a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/

    var country = [[${country}]];
    console.log(country);

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

If you want to run your html offline you can do this, and the JS variable will be always the fixed value of Russia

```
var country = /*[[${country}]]*/ 'Russia';
```